# Insert images in excel sheet automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to insert images into an excel sheet automatically.

For example i would like to show the image path in column B row 2 /pictures/example-file.jpg

This would then load the image in column B row 2.

Is this possible or am i striving for something that cant be done.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say cell **B9** contains the full filespec like:

*C:\TestFolder\sample.jpg*

then try something like:

```
Sub qwertyuiop()
    Dim MyLogo As Shape
    MyFileAndPath = Range("B9").Value
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture MyFileAndPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 70, 70
End Sub
```

will load it.

**EDIT#1:**

This assumes that the links are stored in cells **B1** thru **B1700** and that the pictures will be stored in column **A** next to the links

```
Sub PicturePopulator()
    Dim B As Range, r As Range, a As Range, _
        t As Long, l As Long, w As Long, h As Long
    Set B = Range("B1:B1700")
    For Each r In B
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            MyFileAndPath = r.Value
            Set a = r.Offset(0, -1)
            t = a.Top
            l = a.Left
            h = a.Height
            w = a.Width
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture MyFileAndPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

It is easy to modify the locations.

Comment: This has added one image on top of the cell b9, is there anyway to insert in to cell A9 and then run this down the column? i have 1700 to do

Comment: **Please clarify** ........where are the links and where should the pictures be placed??

Comment: the links are just on a folder on the desktop..... Ideally i would like the image location to be in Column B and the image to be placed in Column A So A2 is the image and B2 is the location of the file. It basically so i can see the image and write a description about it. Thanks Mike

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seem to do it thank you, Is there anyway the image can be resized, Ive tried doing it by row height and width but its bluring.. something like 50x50 Thank you again. Mike